# HTML Dropdown menu not displaying dropdown in certain containers

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I am builing a navigation with the final link being a "More" drop down menu.

```
            <a href="#"><div class="indiv_nav_button"><p class="font_18 white">Children</p></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="indiv_nav_button"><p class="font_18 white">Homeware</p></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="indiv_nav_button"><p class="font_18 white">Gifts</p></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="indiv_nav_button"><p class="font_18 white">Clothing</p></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="indiv_nav_button"><p class="font_18 white">Chocolate</p></div></a>

            <a href="#">
                <div class="indiv_nav_button">

                    <div class="dropdown">

                      <button class="dropbtn "><p class="font_18">More</p></button>

                      <div class="dropdown-content">

                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>

                      </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </a>
```

The dropdown displays fine when outside of a container but I cant seem to get it to display the "dropdown-content" where it sits in the nav. Here is the CSS..

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #696969;
  color: white;

  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

The containers do not have a fixed height. Thanks for your help.

Comment: on hover is not a very user friendly way to open a dropdown, hope you have an onClick event for mobile and keyboard only users

Answer (score 0):

Answered. Was an overflow: hidden; that I had not noticed. Thanks.

Comment: Probably better to just delete the question, especially if that `overflow: hidden` is not in the code provided.